# Select python - Pandas

Tags: python, microsoft-excel, pandas

Estou desenvolvendo um programa em python onde importo dois arquivos xlsx diretamente com a biblioteca Pandas, consigo importa-los facilmente, mas necessito de criar um relatório entre esses dois arquivos.

Como posso fazer?

Comment: CSS, bom dia! Consegue disponibilizar os xlsx? Abraços!

Comment: @lmonferrari Segue os arquivos de exemplo: https://gofile.io/d/5TUFTS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Importando o pacote

```
import pandas as pd
```

Carregando os arquivos:

```
lojas = pd.read_excel('./lojas.xlsx')
produtos = pd.read_excel('./produtos.xlsx')
```

Utilizando join do pandas:

```
novo_df = produtos.set_index('Código da loja').join(lojas.set_index('Código da loja')).reset_index()
```

Reordenando as colunas:

```
novo_df = novo_df[['Código do produto','Nome do produto','preço','Código da loja','Nome da loja']]
```

Saída:

```
novo_df

Código do produto   Nome do produto                                  preço      Código da loja  Nome da loja
          1A        Corretivo líquido 18ml água 930761 Bic            5.70               100        Penha
          2A        Caneta esferográfica 1.0mm cristal                1.40               100        Penha
          3A        Lápis plástico preto evolution Pijama 1106666 ... 4.00               100        Penha
          2A        Caneta esferográfica 1.0mm cristal                1.38               101        Lins de Vasconcelos
          1A        Corretivo líquido 18ml água 930761 Bic            5.75               101        Lins de Vasconcelos
...
```

Sobre o join:

> Junte colunas com outro DataFrame no índice ou em uma coluna-chave.
> Junte de forma eficiente vários objetos DataFrame por índice de uma
> vez, passando uma lista.

[Documentação](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html)

---

**Update**

Como o requerimento da pergunta mudou vou colocar este update aqui.

Importando o pacote

```
import pandas as pd
```

Carregando os arquivos

```
lojas = pd.read_excel('./lojas.xlsx')
produtos = pd.read_excel('./produtos.xlsx')
```

Criando novo data frame e reordenando a apresentação das colunas

```
novo_df = produtos.set_index('Código da loja').join(lojas.set_index('Código da loja')).reset_index()
novo_df = novo_df[['Código do produto','Nome do produto','preço','Código da loja','Nome da loja']]
```

Criando um "filtro" para verificar os menores preços agrupados pelo nome do produto e código do produto, depois criamos um novo data frame com os valores filtrados

```
filtro = novo_df.groupby(['Código do produto','Nome do produto'])['preço'].min()
menor_preco_df = novo_df[novo_df['preço'].isin(filtro)].sort_values(by = ['Código da loja']).reset_index(drop = True)
```

Aqui criamos dois data frames guardando informações diferentes para depois criarmos um dicionário, o intuito é criar uma coluna com listas

```
df1 = menor_preco_df.groupby(['Código da loja','Nome da loja'])['Nome do produto'].apply(list).reset_index()
df2 = menor_preco_df.groupby(['Código da loja','Nome da loja'])['preço'].apply(list).reset_index()
df2.drop(columns = {'Código da loja','Nome da loja'}, inplace = True)
dicionario1 = pd.concat([df1,df2], axis = 1).to_dict('index')
```

Aqui imprime a primeira parte do problema

```
for chave, valor in dicionario1.items():
    print(f"{valor['Código da loja']} - {valor['Nome da loja']}")
    for v,p in zip(valor['Nome do produto'],valor['preço']):
        print(f"   Produto: {v} - R${p}")
    print('')
```

Saída:

```
100 - Penha
   Produto: Lápis plástico preto evolution Pijama 1106666 Bic BT 3 - R$4.0

101 - Lins de Vasconcelos
   Produto: Lápis plástico preto evolution Pijama 1106666 Bic BT 3 - R$4.0

102 - Curuça
   Produto: Corretivo líquido 18ml água 930761 Bic - R$5.5
   Produto: Lápis plástico preto evolution Pijama 1106666 Bic BT 3 - R$4.0

103 - Faria Lima
   Produto: Corretivo líquido 18ml água 930761 Bic - R$5.5

104 - Jardim Brasil
   Produto: Corretivo líquido 18ml água 930761 Bic - R$5.5
   Produto: Caneta esferográfica 1.0mm cristal - R$1.2
```

Aqui criamos o segundo dicionário agrupado por nome do produto e o preço

```
dicionario2 = menor_preco_df.groupby(['Nome do produto','preço'])['Nome da loja'].apply(list).reset_index().to_dict('index')
```

E aqui imprimimos a segunda parte do problema

```
for chave, valor in dicionario2.items():
    print(f"{valor['Nome do produto']}")
    print(f"  - Produto encontrado por R${valor['preço']} nas lojas",', '.join(valor['Nome da loja']),'\n')
```

Saída:

```
Caneta esferográfica 1.0mm cristal
  - Produto encontrado por R$1.2 nas lojas Jardim Brasil 

Corretivo líquido 18ml água 930761 Bic
  - Produto encontrado por R$5.5 nas lojas Curuça, Faria Lima, Jardim Brasil 

Lápis plástico preto evolution Pijama 1106666 Bic BT 3
  - Produto encontrado por R$4.0 nas lojas Penha, Lins de Vasconcelos, Curuça
```

---

**Código completo**

```
import pandas as pd

lojas = pd.read_excel('./lojas.xlsx')
produtos = pd.read_excel('./produtos.xlsx')

novo_df = produtos.set_index('Código da loja').join(lojas.set_index('Código da loja')).reset_index()
novo_df = novo_df[['Código do produto','Nome do produto','preço','Código da loja','Nome da loja']]

filtro = novo_df.groupby(['Código do produto','Nome do produto'])['preço'].min()
menor_preco_df = novo_df[novo_df['preço'].isin(filtro)].sort_values(by = ['Código da loja']).reset_index(drop = True)

df1 = menor_preco_df.groupby(['Código da loja','Nome da loja'])['Nome do produto'].apply(list).reset_index()
df2 = menor_preco_df.groupby(['Código da loja','Nome da loja'])['preço'].apply(list).reset_index()
df2.drop(columns = {'Código da loja','Nome da loja'}, inplace = True)

dicionario1 = pd.concat([df1,df2], axis = 1).to_dict('index')
for chave, valor in dicionario1.items():
    print(f"{valor['Código da loja']} - {valor['Nome da loja']}")
    for v,p in zip(valor['Nome do produto'],valor['preço']):
        print(f"   Produto: {v} - R${p}")
    print('')

dicionario2 = menor_preco_df.groupby(['Nome do produto','preço'])['Nome da loja'].apply(list).reset_index().to_dict('index')
for chave, valor in dicionario2.items():
    print(f"{valor['Nome do produto']}")
    print(f"  - Produto encontrado por R${valor['preço']} nas lojas",', '.join(valor['Nome da loja']),'\n')
```

Comment: Voce usou o Pycharm para mostrar os resultados? Usando aqui ele nao mostra todas colunas , mostra apenas algumas no console, teria que fazer alguma configuracao especifica?

Comment: Estou utilizando o jupyter notebook. No exemplo acima eu cortei as demais linhas pois ficaria muito extenso aqui na resposta. Sobre as colunas eu não sei te informar algo sobre o pycharm pois não utilizo ele.

Comment: Estava lendo sobre o pycharm e parece que existe algo no debug chamado "View as data frame". Segue o [link](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/viewing-as-array.html)

Comment: A resposta te ajudou?

Comment: ajudou demais obrigado pela explicacao ! O link do Pycharm tambem resolveu o problema, adicionei isso no print fez que com imprimisse tudo : print(produtos.head(3000).to_string())

Comment: Que ótimo que te ajudou! Por nada meu caro! Considere em marcar como resposta aceita (não é obrigatório mas é uma boa prática do site). Isso ajuda as pessoas a visualizarem que a pergunta já foi resolvida e também estimula outras pessoas a responderem suas perguntas. [Veja como](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eyLkG.jpg) Grande abraço!

Comment: Acabei de faze-lo , se eu fosse usar o gropu by para agrupar assim como ficaria?                                                                                                               100 - PENHA                                                                                                                      Caneta esferográfica 1.0mm cristal 1,40                                                                                                      
Corretivo líquido 18ml água 930761 Bic 5,70
Lápis plástico preto evolution Pijama 1106666 Bic BT 3 4,00

Comment: Você poderia agrupar assim: `novo_df.groupby(['Código do produto','Nome do produto'])['preço'].sum().reset_index()`. Veja se é o que você imaginava. Abraço!

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/116348/discussion-between-css-and-lmonferrari).